# More -1 votes today (6) than I can recall in 24 hours; quality has not dropped; voting reversed a couple of days ago

Tags: discussion

More -1 votes today (6) than I can recall in 24 hours; quality has not dropped; voting reversed a couple of days ago.

I don't know if it's one person with it in for me, but I don't think it's helpful to have someone who has asked 100s of well received questions banned for asking good questions! I am crazy, but 90%+ of the content I create is not.

Answer (score 0):

More down and close votes

[What is the difference between sublimity and fearsome things?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/108266/what-is-the-difference-between-sublimity-and-fearsome-things)

I think someone is trying to bully me to be honest, a user with enough rep to close questions. It is a specialist question, but I don't see what's wrong with it, and requires no more expertise to answer than many questions that pop up and are quickly answered.